# Generating a Primary Key Column by using the specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to insert the numbers that fall between the Start and End column in the column "**NumberList**" (This should include both the Start and End numbers).

[image: SQL result]

The query that I am using to get the above result is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number      
, CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('0',16-LEN(Number)) AS 'Start' 
, CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('9',16-LEN(Number)) AS 'End'
,NULL 'NumberList'      
FROM  Table
```

Could you please help me with the following as I would like the **NumberList** column to be a *Primary Key* too

Comment: As there can only be one primary key (thus **primary**), it needs to read *I would like the NumberList column to be the Primary key too*. Also, can you please specify WHY you want that `NumberList`? Store start and end as bigints, and the current value, too. Then the question whether a number is in `NumberList` can be reduced to the question whether it is >= start and <= end. Also, storing numbers as strings - **baaaah**!

Comment: You can make it a unique constraint if that's what you're after. If you want an index on it then you can always use NumberList as the key field in a non-clustered index. You can't have two primary keys.

Comment: Oh, and in addition: The "table" we're seeing above is the result of a `SELECT`. There can not be a primary key in that.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Sorry actually I will be using the `SELECT` to push the data into a #Temp table, and the NumberList alone will be Primary Key in the #Temp Table which will be created prior to the `SELECT` code. The NumberList should only contain data within the range of the Start and End.
For Example 
4895470000000000 --Including the Start
4895470000000001
4895470000000002
.
.
.
4895479999999998
4895479999999999 --Including the End

Hope this helps, please do let me know if you need more info so that you can help me out.

Comment: I understand *what* you want to do. I simply fail to understand *why* you want to do that. Maybe you could explain what you actually want to achieve? If you do what you say, the temporary table will consume an enormous amount of memory. And having a PK on the column will not help with anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Create function GetNumbersList (@intStart as bigint, @intEnd as bigint)
returns  varchar(max)
as
begin
    DECLARE @num INT = @intStart
    DECLARE @numberlist as varchar(max)=''
    WHILE(@num<=@intEnd)
    begin
        set @numberlist=@numberlist + cast(@num as varchar(20)) + N' '
        SET @num = @num + 1
    end
return(rtrim(@numberlist))
End
GO
select Number
, CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('0',16-LEN(Number)) AS 'Start' 
, CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('9',16-LEN(Number)) AS 'End'
, dbo.GetNumbersList (CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('0',16-LEN(Number)), CONVERT(VARCHAR,Number) + REPLICATE('9',16-LEN(Number))) as [NumbersList]
from Table`

Comment: Please, I know it is tempting to answer this question, but I smell a totally bullshit solution, so before answering, let's please wait until the OP tells us what he wants to achieve, so maybe we can suggest a better solution...

Comment: I've just started on StackOverflow, so perhaps I'm not familiar with the procedures. I posted this following Jody's last comment explaining the serial list of numbers required. Sorry if I've done the wrong thing.

Comment: You didn't really do anything wrong. I'm just trying to say: If you really think about his requirement, would you have an idea what problem this is supposed to solve?

Comment: There could be: the list of serialised numbers might be an accepted  format for populating a calendar. I didn't give the larger scope much thought.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar to make the question more clear the _Number_ column is a BIN (First 6 digits of a Cardnum). So what I am trying to do here is by running the `Select` statement we get a list of BIN's that's called number. Now what I need to do is get all the Cardnums that fall under the BIN Range 4895470000000000 to 4895479999999999.
I had used between clause in the query but it seems to take a lot of time to run. Hence I am actually trying to get the query execution time down.

Comment: @Joby I still don't get what you want to achieve. If you want to check whether a cardnum belongs to a certain bin, just `SELECT Number WHERE Cardnum >= Start and Cardnum <= End`. Just calculate for your example number in the comment above **how long the string would be** if you actually added all the Cardnums (hint: at least 9999999999 * 16 bytes = 149 GB!!!). What you're trying to do does not speed up anything! On the contrary. Don't do that. Instead, post a new question that shows your original approach and ask for tips to speed that up.

Comment: Make `Start` and `End` numbers, not strings. Then, add an index that contains both of these columns. **That** would probably speed things up.

Comment: Thorsten you are right, I just messed by things though. Thanks throwing light on the same. 

@cloudsafe Thanks for taking the effort on putting a function. 

Both of you are doing great...